# Can't print full results (everything after a space is gone)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'll try to be as specific as possible.

I have a database table from which I'm going to print information. The easiest way to do this is by doing something like this:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("server","user","pass","dbname");  
$users_result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table blabla");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($users_result))
    echo $row['column_to_echo'];
}   
mysqli_close($con);
```

If this query returned one row, with an address, the outcome on the screen would be something like this *"My street 14"* Right? And that's how it works as well. So that's great. Exactly what I want.

HOWEVER:

I need to have these SQL queries in functions, because the queries are dynamic based on who's loading the page.

So a function like that looks something like this;

```
function getUserAddress($userid)
{
    $con=mysqli_connect("server","user","pass","dbname");

    $users_result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table blabla");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($users_result)) {
        return $row['column_to_echo'];
    }   
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

And I use it by doing this:

```
<?php $address = getUserAddress(current_user_id); echo $address; ?>
```

So in this case, we can safely assume that the string being returned by the function is the same string as used in my first example, right? (given the correct ID is being sent into the function).

This is **NOT** the case.. I would only get the first word on my screen. Meaning the function isn't returning the full string, and I have *no* idea why.

On my screen it would appear as *"My"*, instead of *"My street 14"*. And that is my problem.

Does anyone have any clue as to why this is happening?

Comment: Dont connect and close you connection everytime in a function. Open a connection once and close it at the end.

Comment: `while() { return }` makes no sense. You're exiting the loop anyways, so why loop in the first place? You'll never get anything EXCEPT the first row of data. and your mysql_close() will never get executed (unless there's no data at all),b ecause the function terminates as soon as you fetch that first row.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite your function like this

```
function getUserAddress($userid)
{
    $con=mysqli_connect("server","user","pass","dbname");

    $users_result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table blabla");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($users_result)) {
        $str.=$row['column_to_echo']." ";
    }  
    mysqli_close($con); 
    return($str);        
}
```

### Problem :

You were actually making use of a **`return`** inside the **`while`** loop which just returned the first value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
function getUserAddress($userid)
{
    $con=mysqli_connect("server","user","pass","dbname");    
    $users_result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `column` FROM table blabla");    
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($users_result)
    mysqli_close($con);
    return $row;              
}
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: `mysqli_close($con);` will never execute beacause it's after `return` statement.

Comment: Not only that, it also returns full row instead of column value